# Flask-RESTPlus - How to get query arguments?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I'm curious how I can take query arguments coming from the GET method in Flask-RESTPlus. I didn't managed to find an example in the documentation.

I have previously used pure flask and the way I was doing it was by calling 'request.args.get()' from the flask library. Any ideas how to achieve this in RESTPlus?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the most correct solution I found is to use the [request parser](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parsing.html):

```
parser = api.parser()
parser.add_argument('user', location='args', help='Queried user')
```

It is discontinued from RESTPlus. But it is not going any time soon as they have mentioned.

Comment: If it is gonna be deprecated, what is the alternative for this? PS I'm looking for something that can also be passed to `@api.expect()` to generate the Swagger doc

Comment: Hello meshde. You found a alternative? I have exactly the same problem

Comment: @meshde Looks like a cleaner way is to use the `param` decorator. `@api.param('flag', description='description', type='boolean')`

Comment: @Vadman yes this is clean but how are they then accessed inside the function? I assume there should be a flask-restplus method for this; feels nasty to use flasks `request.args`

Answer (score 14):

It's a Flask plugin, it shouldn't be breaking the Flask interface. So you should be able to get them from `flask.request` as always:

```
import flask

...

print(flask.request.args.get("name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use **request.args.get()** to get the arguments .Specify the name the argument name passed in the parenthesis

*Example*

```
name = request.args.get("name")
```

*Sample code in project*

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
  
app = Flask(__name__)
  
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def home():
    if(request.method == 'GET'):
        name = request.args.get("name")
        return jsonify({'name ': name })
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```